# Java Audio file read and Creating Echo effect

Tags: java

I have just started learning Java and I have to deliver a assignment in Which I have to read an Audio (.wav) File and Create echo effect of the audio file and save it without using any external library. Kindly guide me from where exactly to start. Although I have a basic knowledge about C++ upto functions and a little about Classes & Objects. Looking forward for the right direction as I am short of time! 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a working example here : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/Anexampleofplayingasoundwithanechofilter.htm

Comment: Is it not using Java Sound API ?
Actually I have to do it without any external API :/

Comment: it is java api javax imports are part of JDK

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation but this program is not working for some of the .wav files.
secondly for mp3 files can i use the same code or there would be different logic for the Mp3 audio files?

Comment: if i remember correctly java api can only play 16bit 44.100HZ sampled wav files. Mp3 files are not nately supported by jre you need to use an external library for that

Comment: Thanks again and one thing is left which is how can i save this to my disk?
I have looked for different codes but I am looking for shortest method.
if you can help me in that as well..

Thanks :)